# How to statically link an extension to Xerial SQLite JDBC library?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am using [Xerial](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) SQLite library in Java and want to add memstat extension to the compiled jar. They add some extensions by adding the file [here](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/main/ext), compiling that together with SQLite and registering the functions.

How can I load an SQLite memstat extension from my Java code similarly (which is an eponymous virtual table)?